# How to change the color of results from leaflet-knn on the map

Tags: leaflet

I have displayed the the result markers for the leaflet-knn on the map with following code:

```
const myloc = new L.LatLng(13.7433242, 100.5421583);

var gjLayer = L.geoJson(testCities, {
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        content = "<b>Name:</b> " + feature.properties.name;
        layer.bindPopup(content);
    }
});

var longitude = myloc.lng,
    latitude = myloc.lat;

var res = leafletKnn(gjLayer).nearest(
            [longitude, latitude], 5, distance);

for (i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    map.addLayer(res[i].layer);
}
```

Now I want to change the color of this marker that is added or I want to change the icon.

Can anybody tell me how can I do?

Comment: And what's the code that instantiates those markers? Because [`leaflet-knn`](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-knn) returns latlngs, not markers.

Comment: @IvanSanchez I am not sure.. I just use leaflet-knn and res[i].layer show me marker on the map

Comment: Please include relevant code. Include the leaflet-knn query at the very least. And remember about https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @IvanSanchez I have updated the question

Comment: And I guess you haven't tried adding some style rules in your `L.geoJson()` ?

Comment: I have tried adding     style: {
        color: "red", 
        fillColor: "red", 
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    }, to geoJson but it didnot worked

Answer (score 0):

Leaflet-knn is agnostic when it comes to the representation of the results - it relies on the existing `L.Layer`s: it [takes a `L.GeoJSON` as an input](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-knn/blob/4a6e0571fd5c0bbb7e0b048b2e6d0d52fa3c6f57/index.js#L6) and then [iterates through all its members](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-knn/blob/4a6e0571fd5c0bbb7e0b048b2e6d0d52fa3c6f57/index.js#L10) in order to [fetch all their coordinates](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-knn/blob/4a6e0571fd5c0bbb7e0b048b2e6d0d52fa3c6f57/index.js#L50) (in the case of polylines and polygons) and then [store a reference to the `L.Layer` for each of its coordinates](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-knn/blob/4a6e0571fd5c0bbb7e0b048b2e6d0d52fa3c6f57/index.js#L45).

The results of a leaflet-knn search include the *original `L.Layer`* from the `L.GeoJSON` that was passed at instantiation time.

Either symbolize your GeoJSON afterwards, as [explained in the Leaflet tutorials](https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/), or create new markers/symbols for the results after each query.

---

Right now your code is relying on the default symbolization of GeoJSON data (instantiate a `L.Marker` with a `L.Icon.Default` for points). I suggest the approach of displaying your `L.GeoJSON` in the map to ensure that it looks like you want it to (even if it's a partial set of the data), then implementing the leaflet-knn search.